# Sort and add sequence number to nested items in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have MongoDB collection with following documents:

```
{
    "name": "First parent",
    "items": [
        { "name": "First child", "value": 32 },
        { "name": "Second child", "value": 76 },
        { "name": "Third child", "value": 13 }
    ]
}
{
    "name": "Second parent",
    "items": [
        { "name": "Fifth child", "value": 16 },
        { "name": "Sixth child", "value": 15 }
    ]
}
{
    "name": "Third parent",
    "items": [
        { "name": "Fourth child", "value": 56 }
    ]
}
```

I would like to:

- Sort children by `items.value` in each parent from (desc),
- Sort parents by `items.value` of first (highest) child (desc),
- Add `items.order` to each child.

So desired output should be:

```
{
    "name": "First parent",
    "items": [
        { "name": "Second child", "value": 76, "order": 1 }, // Should be first in array, because 76 < 32 < 13. Should have order: 1, because 76 is highest value of all children in collection.
        { "name": "First child", "value": 32, "order": 3 },
        { "name": "Third child", "value": 13, "order": 6 }
    ]
}
{
    "name": "Third parent",
    "items": [
        { "name": "Fourth child", "value": 56, "order": 2 } // Should have order: 2, because 56 is second highest value of all children in collection.
    ]
}
{
    "name": "Second parent",
    "items": [
        { "name": "Fifth child", "value": 16, "order": 4 },
        { "name": "Sixth child", "value": 15, "order": 5 }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to do that? I only have this (without `items.order` property):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$items" },
    { "$sort": { "items.value": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "items": { "$push": "$items" }}
    },
    { "$sort": { "items.value": -1 } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a key to get the first value of the first element of an item array. Then sort by it.

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$items"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "items.value": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      topValue: {
        $first: "$items.value"
      },
      "items": {
        "$push": "$items"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "topValue": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      topValue: 0
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/32zGRyc2UE5)

Comment: Thank you, however I have no `items.order` in database, so I need to create it during query.

Comment: Thats fine, no issues.

Comment: If you answer helps you please tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question